# Creating a c++ program to double and triple the number of integers based on whether they are odd or even

Tags: c++

I am looking for help with a program that will take any number of digits in an integer and if the number is odd then it will double each integer. If the number is even it will triple each integer. Ex. 123 = 112233 or 122 = 111222222. I looking for a way to take the formula I have an run it for any amount of numbers.  Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num1, answer;
    cin >> num1;
    answer = num1 % 2;

    if (answer == 1)
    {
        cout << num1 % 1000/100 << num1 % 1000/100 << num1 % 100/10 << num1 % 100/10 << num1 % 10 << num1 % 10;
    }

        else if (answer == 0)
        {
            cout << num1 % 1000/100 << num1 % 1000/100 << num1 % 1000/100 << num1 % 100/10 << num1 % 100/10 << num1 % 100/10 << num1 % 10 << num1 % 10 << num1 %10;
        }

    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

As of right now it will only do numbers that are 3 digits in length. Is there a way to do these formulas for any number?

Comment: Put the digits in strings?

Comment: What about using loops? Also you don't really have a result number, but just output appearance.

Comment: Please clarify. Do you want your output as an `int` (or `long`, or whatever), or as a string?

Comment: I think having the output as a string will be easier for me. I new to c++ so have never encountered long before. I'm going to try the second answer first and see if I can get it to work with for what I need.

Answer (score 0):

This works for any integer that is within the max value of an integer. If you need bigger numbers you can use the identifier `long` to increase the size of `int`, for anything bigger I recommend `boost\multiprecision`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int convert(int param) {
    int out = 0;
    int powerOfTen = 0;
    int temp;
    int loopAmount;

    if (param % 2 == 0) {
        loopAmount = 3;
    }
    else {
        loopAmount = 2;
    }

    while (param > 0) {
        temp = param % 10;
        param /= 10;

        for (int i = 0; i < loopAmount; i++) {
            out += (temp * pow(10, powerOfTen++));
        }
    }

    return out;
}
```

Comment: "program that will take any number of digits[.]" This can't, you know it can't, and the suggestion of using boost::multiprecision to cover that problem is utter overkill.

Comment: But aren't you cherry picking that quote from the original post? The whole thing reads "program will take any number of digits in an **integer** and if the number is odd then it will double each integer. If the number is even it will triple each integer." As for suggesting boost::multiprecision, what was a suggestion for some time in the future if the original poster wants to expand to much larger numbers.

Comment: Any number of digits is any number of digits and integer doesn't necessarily imply `int`. That said, I don't have a good solution to the infinite case because to determine odd or even you need the last digit. To get the last digit either the integer needs to be input twice or you need infinite RAM to hold the integer. I'm pulling the downvote because you shouldn't have to pay for a poorly worded question.

Comment: Setting aside the issue of "any number of digits" for a moment, @Stephen's solution works fine IMHO, apart from one issue. The `pow` requires conversion to and from float. For larger integers, precision issues start to creep in. If I convert your `int`s to `long`s, and try the number `123456`, I get `1122334455664`. An integer `pow` implementation would solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can't really be done because either you need to know if the number is odd or even ahead of time or have infinite RAM to hold a potentially infinite length integer.

A simple approach that will handle any length of string up until you run your computer out of memory:

- Read the user input into a `std::string`.
- Test that all of the characters in the string are valid digits. If any aren't, the user didn't input a valid integer.

  - Hint: use `isdigit`, and a range-based for loop or `std::all_of` from the algorithm library
  - Hint: you may need to test the first character for a negative sign. If you do, remove the negative sign from the input string (`std::string::substr` should help here) and insert it in the output stream.
  - Print an error message and `return` if any characters are not digits.
- Test the last character for odd or even

  - Hint: an easy way to get the last character in the string is `std::string::back`.
  - Hint: You can convert convert the last character into an `int`, for many common character encodings, with `int lastdigit = lastchar - '0';`
  - Really cheap hack: in ASCII encoding, the one most likely to be used, the characters for odd numbers all have odd encodings. In this non-portable case `lastchar % 2` is sufficient.
  - If character is odd set a repeat counter to 2
  - If character is even set a repeat counter to 3
- For each digit in the string

  - Insert the digit into the output stream repeat counter times. This can be done with a for loop, but there are a large number of faster methods.

Answer (score -1):

You can just strip digits from a copy of the number and add them up. E.g., to repeat digits three times:

```
long result = 0;
long copy = num;
long power = 1;
while (copy > 0)
{
    long digit = copy % 10;
    result += digit*111*power;
    copy /= 10;
    power *= 1000;
}
```

I'll leave the two-digit case for you to figure out...

---

Edit: Standard integers don't get you very far with this problem it seems. Changed them to `long`.

Comment: Down-voter care to explain? As far as I can tell, this works, and doesn't involve strings or floating-point conversion, as has been suggested in other comments/answers.

Comment: "program that will take any number of digits[.]" This can't, you know it can't, and the arbitrary length solution is actually less complicated than what you propose.

Comment: I read the question as asking for a generalisation of a 3 digit algorithm to N digits. I don't think OP meant the phrase "Any number" to mean a complete disregard of all fixed-width integral types. In fact, the slightly-extended quote is "program that will take any number of digits **in an integer**". Clearly two people read the question the same way, so perhaps ask the OP for clarification before down-voting everything that doesn't fit your interpretation.